# SQL error or missing database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to fix sql error in my java code.

Error message:

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "transaction": syntax error)

SQL query:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transaction(id_transaction INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id_client INTEGER, id_product INTEGER, transaction_date DATE NOT NULL,"
            + " FOREIGN KEY(id_client) REFERENCES client(id_client),"
            + " FOREIGN KEY(id_product) REFERENCES product(id_product))";
```

Maybe im blind but there are commas, spaces, both foreign key columns created, tables referenced too.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: on first i wanted to post some java code if it could help. is is possible to remove tag after creating post?

Comment: Sure, just click [edit] under your post.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

TRANSACTION IS A KEYWORD

change to a new table name

Comment: thanks, i checked most common things but didn't think about keyword.

Comment: happened to me once.